# Is it possible to validate the root element in Schematron?

Tags: xml, schematron

How can I check that the root element of an XML file has a specific name?

I can correctly assert whether the root has a specific attribute like this:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
    <pattern id="1">
        <rule context="root_element">
            <assert test="@OBJID">Missing OBJID.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
```

In this case, I'd like to test that the root element is `root_element`.

For example, this should fail (but it doesn't):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mets OBJID="123">
    <Age>30</Age>
</mets>
```

For completeness, I am testing using `unittest` in python 3.

Any link to some documentation about this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "/" to create a rule that fires on the document itself. Then assert the presence of an element named "root_element".

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
  <pattern id="1">
    <rule context="/">
      <assert test="root_element">Root element should be named "root_element".</assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.

Comment: In case somebody is using a default namespace, this is how I did it. 

The XML to validate:
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root_element xmlns="http://www.example.com">
</root_element>`
The validating schema:
`<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
    <ns prefix="name_space" uri="http://www.example.com"/>
    <pattern id="1">
        <rule context="/">
            <assert test="name_space:root_element">The root level element must be "root_element"</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>`